# String is empty after first iteration in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm replacing the contents in a string using a setTimeout-function. The code looks as follows:

```js
(function ($) {

"use strict";

/* 
GENERAL DESCRIPTION:

 */

$(document).ready(function () {

    var page_title = $(".page-content")[0].title;
    var replacement_string = "åpöälokjixrytgöh";

    //$(window).scroll(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {

        var fixed = $(".changing-title");          
        var fixed_position = $(".changing-title").offset().top;
        var fixed_height = $(".changing-title").height();

        var title_array = [];
        var offset_array = [];
        var height_array = [];

        var $pageGridPictures = $(".page-grid-picture");

        $pageGridPictures.each(function (index, element) {

            var $this = $(element);

            title_array.push(element.title);
            offset_array.push($this.offset().top);
            height_array.push($this.height());

        });

        for (var i = 0; i < offset_array.length; i++) {


            if (fixed_position + fixed_height > offset_array[i] && fixed_position + fixed_height < offset_array[i + 1]) {
                if (title_array[i] !== fixed.text()) {

                    var j;
                    var text_one = title_array[i];
                    var text_two = "";

                    fixed.text(title_array[i]);

                    for (j in title_array[i]) {
                        (function (j) {
                            setTimeout(function () {

                                text_two = text_one.substring(0, j) + replacement_string[j] + text_one.substring(j + 2, text_one.length);
                                fixed.text(text_two);

                                if (j == text_one.length - 1) {
                                    fixed.text(text_one);
                                }

                            }, 80 * j);
                        }(j))
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1200);
                });
             })(jQuery);
```

The problem is that the last substring added to text_two in the setTimeout-function is empty after the first iteration. It works the first time. It then contains the correct substring and has the correct length. After that it's just empty. Why is that? I'm going crazy over here! ^^

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can read through your code, and have a stab at what might be wrong (someone might actually get it right) but its far easier to fix your issue when you demo it. Create a [mcve] using stack snippets is perhaps the best way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @Teshte Yes, I have. First time through the loop the value of text_one is the one it's supposed to be. The iterations after text_one is empty. Is it because the variable is declared before the loop itself? Because that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @BigMac, create a demo so we can see your problem live